# Show entire Sass-nesting-path/levels in the top?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm coding some colorschemes (in Sass), where one super-duper-parent-class, controls all the children. And I keep finding myself on screens such as this:

[image: PhpStorm code]

... thinking to myself: 'Now, which colorscheme am I in now?'.

I'm currently fixing it, by splitting the code into several files, which kinda solves it, but not in an ideal way. It means a lot of file-switching. And also if I have a `.open`- / `.closed`-class or a `.missing`- / `.present`-class, then I have to find that and 'climb down the tree' to ensure that I make the change in the correct spot. Quite tedious!

I was hoping that I could find a plugin, that could (at all times, regardless of where the cursor is), could display the nesting-levels in a fixed status-bar at the top of the screen ( kind of like that I can position my cursor *on a bracket* to see the [matching one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52dN.jpg) ).

An example of what I'm trying to find is, if I put the cursor inside `ul.menu-main__current-menu-item__missing li a {`, that it then would show a status-bar in the top:

```
#header >> &.green-colorscheme >> ul.menu-main__current-menu-item__missing li a
```

Can I achieve this, somehow? If not, - then how do I stop getting lost in my code?

### Attempts

- Looked into bookmarks.
- Looked into code folding.
- I'm trying [Rainbow Brackets](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets) at the moment.

None of which solves the issue as well as my suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE can already do this for Sass/SCSS (since 2018.1 or so, I do not remember exact version number; could do that for HTML/PHP for a long time).

[image]

Make sure that you enabled Breadcrumbs for Sass language at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Breadcrumbs`

[image]